# PGSQL Postgres Update based on numeric range on a text column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with IDs, some have letters, most do not. And associated points with those IDs. The IDs are stored as text.
I would like to add points to a given range of IDS that ARE integers and give them all the same points. 535.

I have found a way using a subquery to SELECT the data I need, but it appears that updating it is another matter. I would love to be able to only get data that is CAST-able without a subquery. however since it errors out when it touches something that isn't a number, that doesn't seem to be possible.

```
select * from (select idstring, amount from members where idstring ~ '^[0-9]+$') x
WHERE
CAST(x.idstring AS BIGINT) >= 10137377001
and
CAST(x.idstring AS BIGINT) <= 10137377100
```

What am I doing ineficiently in the above, and how an I update the records that I want to?
In a perfect world my statement would be as simple as:

```
UPDATE members SET amount = 535 
WHERE idstring >= 10137377001
AND idstring <= 10137377100
```

But since Idstring both contains entries that contain letters and is stored as text, it complicates things significantly. TRY_CAST would be perfect here, however there is no easy equivalent in postgres.

An example of the ids in the table might be

```
A52556B
36663256
6363632900B
3000525
```

ETC.

Comment: I found out that you don't need to do any conversion with postgresql. It just natively converts text to numbers where possible when you use the < and > operands. Much simpler but completely hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`TO_NUMBER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) together with your regular expression predicate, like so:

```
UPDATE members
   SET amount = 535
 WHERE idstring ~ '^[0-9]+$'
   AND to_number(idstring, '999999999999') BETWEEN 10137377001 AND 10137377100
```

[Working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=77634f5315fd375a848db05b6c6c6451)

Answer (score 0):

You can encase the typecast and integer comparison within a `CASE` statement.

```
UPDATE members
SET amount = COALESCE(amount, 0) + 535
WHERE CASE WHEN idstring ~ '^[0-9]+$'
           THEN idstring::BIGINT BETWEEN 10137377001 AND 10137377100
           ELSE FALSE END;
```

Here I've assumed you might want to add 535 rather than setting it explicitly to 535 based on what you said above, but if my assumption is incorrect then `SET amount = 535` is just fine.